# WinAPI: запись данные на диск и считывания данных с диска больших размеров (свыше 4ГБ)

Tags: c++, файлы, winapi, x86-64

Подскажите пожалуйста, что-то туплю и не могу найти, как в 64 разрядном приложении из файла зачитать блок больший, чем 4ГБ, `ReadFile` не помогает (поскольку он для Win32)

И второй вопрос - выделение памяти больший размеров (свыше 4ГБ) ведь можно спокойно через `new` делать? (опять же в 64разрядном приложении) или лучше всякие `VirtualAlloc` использовать?

Comment: можно использовать сишные fredad/fwrite/fseek64, они все идут с size_t

Comment: А для чего вам нужно читать именно единственным вызовом ReadFile? Почему нельзя считать сколь угодно большой блок кусками в цикле? Ну будет у вас вместо одной строчки кода три, только и всего.

Comment: @freim, это конечно так, но если есть много памяти, система и программа 64битные, то почему бы не воспользоваться этим?

Comment: @Zhihar, ReadFile никак не помешает вам работать с большими данными. Просто вы тот же большой блок читаете в цикле за несколько вызовов, а дальше точно так же работаете с ним единым блоком >4Гб. Проблема выеденного яйца не стоит, разве что такой цикл оскорбляет ваше эстетическое чувство. Ну так вынесите его в функцию ReadFile64, и все будет красиво. И уж точно будет на порядок проще, чем городить отображение файла в память.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы же с C++ работаете, ну так и используйте себе спокойно потоки...

Visual C++ 2017, режим x64.

Создаю файл 5Г:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned long long const SIZE = 5ll*1024ll*1024ll*1024ll;
    try {
        char * buf = new char[SIZE];
        for(unsigned long long i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
            buf[i] = i%200;

        cout << (void*)buf << endl;
        ofstream of("test",ios::binary);
        of.write(buf,SIZE);
    } catch(...)
    {
        cout << "Error\n";
    }
}
```

Создался пятигиговый файл, никаких проблем.

Другой программкой (чтоб гарантированно память была чистая) читаю и проверяю:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned long long const SIZE = 5ll*1024ll*1024ll*1024ll;
    try {
        char * buf = new char[SIZE];
        cout << (void*)buf << endl;
        ifstream in("test",ios::binary);
        in.read(buf,SIZE);
        cout << in.good() << endl;
        for(unsigned long long i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
            if ((unsigned char )buf[i] != i%200)
            {
                cout << "Wrong! at i = " << i << endl;
                break;
            };

    } catch(...)
    {
        cout << "Error\n";
    }
}
```

Все нормально отрабатывает, без привлечения каких-то вне-С++-овых сущностей...

P.S. Хотя с моей точки зрения такие куски в память засасывать - все же извращение...

Comment: Harry, ничего не поделать - у меня вообще около 10-16ГБ :) данные обрабатываются и то потому что больше оперативки нет и считывается/записывается кусками. А поясните пожалуйста про ofstream - т.е. это вообще отказ от WinAPI, поскольку мне всякие фишки связанные с правами не нужны, то можно использовать такую запись смело? А как обстоят дела со скоростью - по сравнению с WinAPI, а то я и чтение тогда бы через потоки сделал бы, правда там мне надо многократно из файла считывать т.е. setFilePointerEx использовать (опять же 64битный)

Comment: В режиме x64 тип `streamsize` - 64-битовый, так что проблем никаких нет. Права при работе будут как у пользователя - от имени которого запущена программа. Скорость... Ну, зависит от машины, но поскольку все реализуется все равно через API, то такая же :) А поскольку чтение само по себе операция тормозная, то разницы не будет заметно точно. P.S. Замерил у себя - немногим меньше минуты, порядка 90 Mb/s - словом, дисковая скорость...

Answer (score 4):

Может вообще файл "не читать"? Используя WinAPI можно спроецировать файл в память, см. `CreateFile -> CreateFileMapping -> MapViewOfFile`. Таким образом программа как будто бы работает с боооольшим участком памяти. Есть также некоторая надежда, что система и не будет читать тех кусков файла, которые не понадобятся.

Comment: Да, это может оказаться куда лучшим решением, чем работа с такими количествами памяти.

Comment: не факт, конечно его можно замаппить и работать как с памятью, но скорость будет невысокая, выгоднее считать буфер и работать с ним (учитывая, что мне нужно только последовательное чтение данных - у меня последовательно находятся записи, которые я и обрабатываю и обработав одну запись к ней уже не возвращаюсь)

Comment: @Zhihar ну что там быстрее сказать сложно без измерений, но выделение и ЗАПОЛНЕНИЕ  из файла буфера точно сожрет оперативку, а замапленный файл, может быть, и нет.

Comment: Мне *кажется* (понятно, что надо экспериментировать!), что если нужно обращение последовательное - то отображение в память должно дать неплохой результат. Если постоянно лезть в разные концы - тогда вопрос, конечно. Но! Все же, не XY ли проблема у нас? Не выясняем ли, в какой руке держать микроскоп, а не как забить гвоздь? можно немного подробнее, в чем состоит изначальная задача и что за обработка таких огромных файлов?...

Answer (score 2):

```
// Returns the number of bytes actually read
__int64 ReadFile64(HANDLE hFile, LPVOID buf, __int64 size) {
  DWORD len;
  DWORD bytesRead;
  __int64 readTotal = 0;

  _ASSERTE (size > 0);
  do {
    len = (size > (unsigned __int64)ULONG_MAX) ? ULONG_MAX : (unsigned long)size;
    if (!ReadFile(hFile, buf, len, &bytesRead, NULL)) ProcessError();
    buf = (LPBYTE)buf + bytesRead;;
    size -= bytesRead;
    readTotal += bytesRead;
  } while (size > 0 && bytesRead == len);

  return readTotal ;
}
```